# htaccess, Always https://www

Tags: .htaccess

Currently using the following to make sure my website always is using www. How would I modify this to be www and https?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Tried this, but ended up with www.www.website if the user had no https but did already have a www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Not sure how to combine the two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make us of {SERVER_PORT} to see if the request is made via regular connection (80), then redirect to the https URL.

This should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: It's unlikely, but would this work if the user types in something like - [https]://website.com  (without the www but still https)

Comment: It's very unlikely users will type https ... but you can implement a similar rewrite rule for port 443

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/http-https-rewriterule-redirect.html) are some nice example, using different methods.