# How do I make sure my site always has the https infront

Tags: .htaccess

Hey guys I have the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will always make sure my ssl is properly showing, but for some reason on google if you are to search the site and than click on its subcatagorys, like services.  It just takes you to site's services and displays it without the https, so it just becomes www.....

How do I fix this?

David

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820724/htaccess-always-https-www

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rewritecond you're using is preventing the urls with www (eg http:// www.site.com/page.html) from being redirected

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sweet thanks!,  Okay so I have another issue

Comment: So from when I first started building my site I had a redirect to a live.php file so in google when you search the site and click on the main result it takes you to site/live.php?  and that file no longer exist nor that code that redirected it.

Comment: if i understand correctly, there's a page (live.php) that's deleted but google didn't update its search results, you can redirect a request of that url to the website home page by using this rewrite rule ( RewriteRule ^live.php$ htt ps://www.site.com/? [R=301,L] ) , (remove the space between htt an ps)

Comment: live.php still accessible?

Comment: i mean are you getting a 404 Not Found?

Comment: Ya but it takes my whole root directory and put it into address bar

Comment: It should be fine now though :)

Comment: ok glad it works, what was the problem?

Comment: Google....just wait for it to update and it could have been my cache?